# Hyperledger Fabric - Samples - 2.2.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, sample

I followed the install process for using samples, but I get an error since the link https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.2.0/hyperledger-fabric-msys_nt-10.0-17763-amd64-2.2.0.tar.gz doesn't exist.

I ran the command below:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s

Clone hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo and checkout v2.2.0
Cloning into 'fabric-samples'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 19, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (19/19), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 6431 (delta 8), reused 2 (delta 1), pack-reused 6412R
Receiving objects: 100% (6431/6431), 3.69 MiB | 9.64 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3350/3350), done.
Updating files: 100% (501/501), done.
error: pathspec 'v2.2.0' did not match any file(s) known to git

Pull Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 2.2.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.2.0/hyperledger-fabric-msys_nt-10.0-17763-amd64-2.2.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9  100     9    0     0     24      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    24

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.2.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/release-2.2/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and the only way I could solve it was by downloading an older version. Try the versions on this page:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html

If it fails to pull the images try it with a sudo.